# ApplicationListener in Spring Security 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I extended ApplicationListener with my own code. In previous versions of Spring Security (e.g. Spring Security 2) there was no need to configure anything to intercept the authentication. But now, I upgraded to SSecurity 3.2 and I cannot make that this class works. I put a breakpoint in the class, but after a log success the control does not stop in this class, and I get some exceptions. My question is: 
Do I need to configure something in my application-context? I put this:

```
   <b:bean id="userAuthenticationListener" class="my.app.security.UserAuthenticationEventListener"/>
```

and nothing more. I saw in other posts things like

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
<security:intercept-url pattern="..."/>
<security:form-login
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authFailureHandler"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"/>
<security:logout success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"
        invalidate-session="true"/>
<security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession"/>
```

But I'm not sure if my code is getting deprecated. If somebody could please give me some lines of where to read, I would be grateful.

Comment: Can you please post the exceptions you're getting?

Comment: I have no exceptions with Spring. The exceptions that I have are related to other classes (my code) that needed the result of UserAuthenticationEventListener.java. So I suspect that my exceptions will not be useful for the discussion. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to do, post your code and configuration along with the errors you're getting (with stacktraces). Without more information it's not easy to give an answer.